# How to transfer data from a dataset to existing excel form's particular worksheet with specific row and columns in c#

Tags: c#, excel, dataset, dbase

I am working on a project in which I have to fetch data from `DBASE` files and then export the data `excel form`.

That `excel form` has more than 10 worksheets having buttons to add rows.

I have retrieved data from `dbase` files in required format (as required in `excel form`) using `OLEDB`.

Now the question is how to send data from datatable to excel forms specific worksheet with desired row and columns.

Also how can I send command to worksheet's button to add required rows?

thats how i fetch Data from dbase files and store it into a datatable.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

   string a = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=d:\\vat;Extended     Properties =dBASE IV; User ID = Admin ;Password =";
   OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
   con.ConnectionString = a;
   con.Open();
   //MessageBox.Show(con.State.ToString());
   string qu = "Select * from abc.dbf ";
   OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter(qu, con);
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
   oda.Fill(dt);
   this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

}
```

There are so many examples are there to export data from data table to excel but almost in each example a new excel form is created. i have to export to an existing excel form which contain near about 10 sheets. Now i want to insert that datatable content to excel sheet named as ABC.XLS and worksheet name is A.

I hope i explained my problem.

Comment: What if you add data directly to excel sheet from Database ?? Ofcourse you can add it from your c# code.

Comment: you can insert into excel using this line in sql server - **Insert into OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 
    'Excel 8.0;Database=D:\testing.xls;', 
    'SELECT * FROM [SheetName$]') select * from YourSQLServerTable**

Comment: Will you please elaborate?

Comment: is it possible with c# with the help of arrays?

Comment: Ofcourse its possible in c#. by creating an instance of - **Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application** you can achieve it but first show me what you have done so far. So that i can help you in better way...

Comment: I have explained again in my question @KrishnrajRana

Comment: I have added code in question @KrishnrajRana

Comment: Please check my answer... and let us know...and again sorry for the late reply...

Answer (score 0):

Below answer may not satisfy your exact requirement but just verify it. 
BTW sorry for the late reply as i was busy with my existing work.

Below code i have used in one of my desktop application. Hope it may help you.

```
public static void ExportToExcel(DataTable dt)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp = null;
            try
            {
                // instantiating the excel application class
                excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook currentWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet currentWorksheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)currentWorkbook.ActiveSheet;
                currentWorksheet.Columns.ColumnWidth = 18;


                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    currentWorksheet.Cells[1, 1] = DateTime.Now.ToString("s");
                    int i = 1;
                    foreach (DataColumn dtColumn in dt.Columns)
                    {
                        // Excel work sheet indexing starts with 1
                        currentWorksheet.Cells[2, i] = dtColumn.Name;
                        ++i;
                    }
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range headerColumnRange = currentWorksheet.get_Range("A2", "G2");
                    headerColumnRange.Font.Bold = true;
                    headerColumnRange.Font.Color = 0xFF0000;
                    //headerColumnRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit();
                    int rowIndex = 0;
                    for (rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < dt.Rows.Count; rowIndex++)
                    {
                        DataRow row = dt.Rows[rowIndex];
                        for (int cellIndex = 0; cellIndex < row.Cells.Count; cellIndex++)
                        {
                            currentWorksheet.Cells[rowIndex + 3, cellIndex + 1] = row.Cells[cellIndex].Value;
                        }
                    }
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range fullTextRange = currentWorksheet.get_Range("A1", "G" + (rowIndex + 1).ToString());
                    fullTextRange.WrapText = true;
                    fullTextRange.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignLeft;
                }
                else
                {
                    string timeStamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("s");
                    timeStamp = timeStamp.Replace(':', '-');
                    timeStamp = timeStamp.Replace("T", "__");
                    currentWorksheet.Cells[1, 1] = timeStamp;
                    currentWorksheet.Cells[1, 2] = "No error occured";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Exception", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (excelApp != null)
                {
                    excelApp.Quit();
                }
            }
        }
```

For reference just refere this [MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/dd264733.aspx).

Good luck...

Comment: i am not able to open specific worksheet from an excel file I am using following code for this          books.Open(mysheet, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
            Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheetFocus = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(3);
            xlWorkSheetFocus.Activate();

Comment: however it open required form but does not set the worksheet 3 as current worksheet by default.  i am getting the error    Object reference not set to an instance of an object. How i can solve this @Krishnraj Rana

Comment: After opening the Required worksheet i would be able to try your Code

Comment: In my answer i assumed that you got data in your **DataTable dt**. So where exactly you got error ???

Comment: Yes i have got data in data table. But i want to transfer data to specific sheet of excel file and according to me to do so i need to firstly open excel form and set the required sheet as active sheet. which is not working for me with above mentioned code(in comments). i am just stuck. I hope that i have expressed my Problem. Please Help Sir @Krishnraj Rana

Comment: @Flanker : Here we have created new instance of *Excel.Application()** that means there is no any worksheet till now in it. So tell me how can you open and set worksheet. As its new instance that means you need to add worksheet as mentioned in above code. Second thing as you said you already got data in your dataTable then just retrieve the records and started inserting it into excel. If you have let say more than one lac records then add top 65k in sheet1 and next 65k in Sheet2. you can add new worksheet **var xlNewSht = (Excel.Worksheet)xlShit.Add(xlShit[1], Type.Missing,Missing,Missing);**

Comment: I am opening existing excel sheet. The variable "mysheet" Contain path of excel sheet i.e string mysheet = @"C:\Users\SINGH\Desktop\vat15\VAT15.xlsx";
            var excelapp = new Excel.Application();
            excelapp.Visible = true;
            Excel.Workbooks books = excelapp.Workbooks;

Comment: i want to open existing excel files's desired worksheet. and want to transfer data to active worksheet and save the data in excel file. if i am doing wrong then how it can be done. @ Krishnraj Rana

Comment: i am waiting for your response sir.